# How to find max values in List<> contain character in C#?

Tags: c#

I have List lstTextBox, this textbox contain like:

```
lstTextBox = { HAPPY - SAD - LOOK- LIKE
            UNI
            PLAT CONTROL - ANDREDDl
            YUP TEN - UIDO
            90932 - 893298 - 902w - 899898s
          }
```

You can see a line: `HAPPY - SAD - LOOK- LIKE` and `90932 - 893298 - 902w - 899898s` include four characters "-". It max values I want to get only 1 line from list contain many characters "-".

I tried with:

`string textFile = lstTextBox.Max(t => t.Contains("-").ToString()).ToString();`

But it returns values "true". I want result like: `90932 - 893298 - 902w - 899898s` or `HAPPY - SAD - LOOK- LIKE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get only 1 line from list contain many characters "-".

Use `string.Split` to split the string and then `OrderByDescending` with the count, take the the first element from ordered collection.

```
va firstitem = lstTextBox.OrderByDescending(x=> x.Split('-').Count())
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You count "_". Is space between's string? If user input many strings but only 2 character "-". Like: `YOU CAN GET ANYMORE - AT HERE`. This will fail. `90932 - 893298 - 902w - 899898s` or `HAPPY - SAD - LOOK- LIKE` have many character "-" but will not selected.

Comment: According to OP delimiter is `-`, even if there are spaces those will be treated as single string. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @HariPrasad I think they're pointing out a possible typo: You wrote `_`, but the problem asks for `-`.

Comment: Ahh.. got it, Thanks @Rob. Fixed now :-)